# Can I fly a glider in Europe on a Canadian Glider License?

Tags: glider, easa, transport-canada

I currently live in Canada as a Permanent Resident and I recently received my Canadian Glider Pilot License. I will be going to Europe soon so I was wondering what I have to do to be able to fly a glider there. I will be going to the Netherlands if this makes any difference and I still have my Dutch Citizenship. Do I have to convert my license or just do some extra training?

Also would it help if I got a FAA glider certificate/endorsement on top of my TCCA license?

Comment: Hi Laurens, welcome to aviation.sx!

Comment: Make sure you have the right medical too. US pilots who fly without a medical must get a medical to fly in France.

Comment: I currently have a Cat 1 Medical in Canada.

Comment: If all else fails try finding a local gliding club and see if you can fly with one of their members.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is difficult to convert to EASA. You can find more information [here](https://www.ilent.nl/onderwerpen/transport/luchtvaart/general_aviation__luchtsporters/Brevetten_zweefvliegen_en_ballonvaren/index.aspx) however I suspect the easiest method will simply be for you to phone them up.

I think the bureaucracy will probably be more hassle than it's worth. It's not like Transport Canada where you can just get a FLVC (Foreign Licence Validation Certificate) or whatever (that was a pleasent suprise after our CAA in the UK!).

Comment: TC is short for Transport Canada, and FLVC (Foreign Licence Validation Certificate) is something they issue. I would say both are fairly common, especially for Canadians.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Before EASA you could fly a German-registered glider on almost any nation's glider credential(s). I did it for a year before getting a German SPL just because. No idea if this still exists.

You can certainly fly gliders w/ an instructor. If you are a visitor you're highly unlikely to get to solo a club's glider. Not sure about NL, but in Germany there are places that function as commercial training facilities though technically clubs w/ daily membership.

If the instructor is willing to let you solo, you could simply solo as if you were a regular EASA Land student glider pilot.

I got a British (BGA) Gliding License super easily by email and credit card. I flew several times at really nice places in England and Scotland.

Answer (score -4):

If the glider has Canadian registration, you can fly it anywhere in the world. If it doesn't, it depends on which registration it has and in what country you have to fly. Each country is different, and the further west you go in Europe, the more anal[-retentive] the bureaucrats. UK is the worst, as you go east in Europe it gets easier and more laid back. I have an N-registered glider in Germany so I can fly it any time I want, but I can't fly a D- glider. Unfortunately, to get the correct answer for any country you have to navigate their regulatory bureaucracy, which can be pretty thick in many places.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. Please check the language used in your answer, especially the part about bureaucrats is inappropriate for this site. Can you also provide sources and citation for some of your remarks? Otherwise it's rather just an opinionated comment, but does not really answer the question.

Comment: @SentryRaven he meant [anal-retentive](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+anal-retentive), it's commonly abbreviated to anal per Wikipedia. It's not a vulgar adjective.

Comment: @ymb1 I know what he meant, doesnt make it appropriate language.

Comment: As @SentryRaven stated in his second answer, there is nothing vulgar or inappropriate about the term. Move on.

The answer is the last sentence. It means "You have to do your own homework in each country."